# Flow type with all dynamic keys, but all keys of same type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a Firebase database structured like this:

```
user: {
  cart: {
    "randomid": quantity,
    "randomid": quantity
  }
}
```

Obviously I do not want to hardcode item ids into a flow type. Is there a way to create a type such that every key is a number, something like this:

```
type User = {
    cart: {
        *: number
    }
}
```

I know this is not ideal, but I am stuck with the database structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved like this:

```
type User = {
    cart: {
        [key: string]: number
    }
}
```